# sending email if disk space exceeds

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have a script to calculate available disk space and alert by email if the limit exceeds a given value defined by me. Here is the script:

```
df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' | while read output;
do
    usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1  )
    partition=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }' )
    if [ $usep -ge $Alert ]; then
    MessageSpace="Running out of space \"$partition ($usep%)\" on $(hostname) as on $(date)"
    spacealert
    fi
done
```

Now, the problem is if I have two disks whose limit has exceeded the given limit then it will generate two seperate mails. Can I make it to send just a single email to me. Thanks.

Comment: not directly related to this question, but... in some case the Filesystem column take 2 lines ... to avoid this you can call df with -P flag (--portability, use the POSIX output format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to create a temporary file and write any over-usage alerts to that file.  If, after we go through all the partitions, the file is not empty, an email message is sent:

```
tmpfile="$HOME/.fs_usage_check.tmp"
echo -n "" >"$tmpfile"
df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' | while read output;
do
    usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1  )
    partition=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }' )
    if [ $usep -ge $Alert ]; then
        echo "Running out of space \"$partition  ($usep%)\" on $(hostname) as on $(date)" >>"$tmpfile"
    fi
done
if [ -s "$tmpfile" ] ; then
    mail  -s "Disk Space Warning" someone@host <"$tmpfile"
fi
rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

I am not familiar with the `spacealert` utility that you were using so I substituted `mail` for sending the email.

By the way, I think the awk/while/read statements can be simplified a bit:

```
tmpfile="$HOME/fs_usage_check.tmp"
echo -n "" >"$tmpfile"
df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | awk '{ print $1,$5 }' | while read partition usep ; do
    if [ ${usep%%%} -ge $Alert ]; then
        echo "Running out of space \"$partition  ($usep)\" on $(hostname) as on $(date)" >>"$tmpfile"
    fi
done
if [ -s "$tmpfile" ] ; then
    mail  -s "Disk Space Warning" someone@host <"$tmpfile"
fi
rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

In this simplified form, the `usep` variable changes slightly: it still has the '%' sign attached.  We need the percent sign removed in order to do numeric comparison. Bash has a special parameter expansion for removing such suffixes which looks like `${var%pattern}` or, to remove the longest pattern matching suffix, `${var%%pattern}`.  In our case, because the pattern itself is a percent sign, the same as bash's magic character, we need either to escape it (as in `${usep%\%}`) or to use the longest match command (as in `${usep%%%}`).

Note that the `do while` loop is in a pipeline and therefore in a subshell (I am assuming you are using bash or dash or similar shell).  Thus, none of its environment variables survive out of the loop.  The temporary file, of course, survives and that makes it good for signaling whether a message should be sent.

Comment: really helpful Thanks. Can you explain the use of `usep` as `${usep%%%}` what does the three `%` sign do?

Comment: @Tarun That is tricky.  I added an explanation to the answer.